Trouble parsing and changing Hyperlinks in a Word document
Let me preface this with the fact that I am aware that there's a lot of resources online for this. So many in fact, that I have trouble finding a solution for my particular issue.
The goal:
We have a folder full of word and excel docs, that point to eachother and also other word documents. The network share they were on has been changed, and so links pointing to file://\\old_share\folder\document.doc no longer work. My intention was to go through every document, and change the Address of the links to the new share e.g. file://\\new_share\folder\document.doc.
These word documents are mixed between versions, so some are docx, some are doc, etc.
What I have so far:
I've tried using Python, PowerShell, C#. The exact implementation is almost identical. I open a handle to word.application, then I open the document, and then I try to iterate through the Hyperlinks field and do my work.
For now I would be happy to just print them to the screen so this is my minimal example of what I have so far.
$word                = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$word.Visible        = $false
$word.ScreenUpdating = $false

$folder = "\\new_share\folder"
$docs = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -LiteralPath $folder -file -include '*.doc*'

foreach($doc in $docs){
    $thisDoc = $word.Documents.Open($_.FullName)
    $link = [pscustomobject]@{
           FileName  = $doc.FullName
           HyperLink = $thisDoc.Address            
    }
    Write-Host "$($link.FileName) => $($link.HyperLink)"
    $thisDoc.Close()
}

$Word.Quit()

# cleanup com objects
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

From this I am expecting to see the addresses, so a bunch of (\old_share\folder...), what I get instead is a bunch of Hyperlinks with $null Address fields. I'm sure that I am doing something wrong, but I'd really appreciate any ideas.
using a com object to open the file and read the Hyperlinks field.
I also considered just unzipping the docx files, and changing the links directly inside the xml, but not all documents are docx, and I feel that it is much more slow and complex to do.

[1] Using -Filter is much more efficient that -Include. [2] You loop over the docs with foreach($doc in $docs), but inside the loop you are trying to load the file using $_.FullName. ($_ would only represent the file when looping with $docs | Foreach-Object; in your loop you need to use $doc.FullName) [3] To find the hyperlinks in a Word document, you need to loop over the $doc.Hyperlinkscollection where each of these objects would have an Address property.

To search for and change the hyperlinks .Address properties in Word documents, you need to loop over the documents .Hyperlinks collection as I have already commented.
The below code will do that for you.
$oldPath = '\\old_share\folder\'
$newPath = '\\new_share\folder\'

$word                = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible        = $false
$word.ScreenUpdating = $false

$folder = "\\new_share\folder"
$docs   = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -LiteralPath $folder -File -Filter '*.doc*'

foreach($doc in $docs){
    $updated = $false
    $thisDoc = $word.Documents.Open($doc.FullName)
    $thisDoc.HyperLinks | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.Address -like "*$oldPath*") {
            Write-Host ("Replaced hyperlink '{0}' in document {1}" -f $_.TextToDisplay, $doc.FullName)
            $_.Address = $_.Address -replace [regex]::Escape($oldPath), $newPath
            $updated = $true
        }
    }
    $thisDoc.Close($updated)
}

$Word.Quit()

# cleanup com objects
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($thisDoc)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()


Nicely done. As an aside, I just discovered inconsistent enumeration behavior with .HyperLinks (doesn't affect your answer, due to use of ForEach-Object); see GitHub issue #24611

Your example works, thank you for taking the time! However it seems that the issue are the word documents themselves. This snippet still returns null values when I try to access the individual Hyperlinks. When I create a new Word document and add test links inside, the script works fine.
The docs are using the old format, so I'm assuming this is the issue. However I don't know of another way to edit the links or why the old format isn't working...
I'll mark your answer as the solution, thank you!

@user2268909 That is really strange indeed. If I test with documents in Word 97 format it works without a problem.. (I'm using PowerShell 5.1) Perhaps you can try a different method of looping over the individual hyperlinks as described by @mklement0 in his comment. Does foreach ($lnk in $thisDoc.HyperLinks){..} (and change $_.Address into $lnk.Address) return hyperlink objects or are these still null in your old docs?

@mklement0 not that I'm familiar enough with PowerShell to argue the point, but since the Hyperlinks collection does not have either a GetEnumertor or ForEach member, I wonder whether PowerShell could reliably " do the right thing" with the syntax in approaches 4 and 5 in the submission on GitHub. Even given the hidden _NewEnum member.

@jonsson: I haven't even looked that closely, but the argument is simple: if the pipeline (+ ForEach-Object) and the foreach statement know how to enumerate such instances and do, there's no good reason not to also do it in the context of the intrinsic .ForEach() method and member-access enumeration. In other words: all of PowerShell's enumeration contexts should behave the same.
